# How to disable Choose Column menu in Ms. Dynamic Nav 2009

Tags: dynamics-nav

In RoleTailored Client (RTC) in Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2009, User can add column in the list of Order by right click on list => Choose Column . I just to disable Choose Column context menu So that user can't perform that function. how could I do that ?

thx you for your help,
Makara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think that's possible, sorry. If your license permits it, you could consider customizing the list page to only include the columns you want the user to see, or copying the list page and customizing the copy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. I'd recommend removing the columns from the form/page's listview so that they aren't available on Choose Columns.

You may need to consult with your NAV partner if you don't have the necessary permissions in your licence to edit forms and pages.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Profile" that you assign to the user, and place check mark in column "Disable personalization" is one of the way. 
But, it will also block the user to customize navigation pane or customize page.